# How can I filter out in haskell?

Tags: haskell, filter

I know about the `filter` function but I'm wondering how I can filter out. For example: `filter odd [1,2,3] = [1,3]`, but I want `filter (not(odd)) [1,2,3] = [2]` (yes I know there's an even function but this is just an example of it). I don't know if there's a separate function that I don't know about or if there's just something I can add to the argument. Thanks. note: I can't use the GHC.Utils.Misc filterOut.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were quite close, you can use:

```
filter (not . odd) [1, 2, 3]
```

here we thus construct a function `\x -> not (odd x)`, that will thus retain all elements that are *not* odd, so even.

Answer (score 4):

One might also use the `partition` function from `Data.List`.

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
Prelude Data.List> (odds, evens) = partition odd lst
Prelude Data.List> odds
[1,3,5,7]
Prelude Data.List> evens
[2,4,6,8]
```

Another alternative would be to use a list comprehension in place of `filter`.

```
Prelude Data.List> [x | x <- lst, not $ odd x]
[2,4,6,8]
```